# PHP comparing value of one and key of another array

Tags: php, arrays

In order to import database data with ease, I have tried to write some php code in order to help me out. I have 2 arrays, "list" wich is regular aray. Other "order1" is an associative array. I'm trying to compare value of first with keys of second to make list that I need.. Something like multi find and replace..

array: list

```
[0] => Apple 
[1] => Apple 
[2] => Apple 
[3] => Apple 
[4] => Bannana 
[5] => Mango 
[6] => Mango 
[7] => Mango 
[8] => Mango 
[9] => Mango 
[10] => Pear 
[11] => Pear 
[12] => Pear 
[13] => Pear 
[14] => Pineaple 
[15] => Strawberry 
[16] => Strawberry 
[17] => Watermelon 
[18] => Watermelon 
[19] => Watermelon 
[20] => Watermelon
```

array: order1

```
[Apple] => 1
[Bannana] => 2
[Mango] => 3
[Pear] => 4
[Pineaple] => 5
[Strawberry] => 6
[Watermelon] => 7
```

I want to get:

```
1
1
1
1
2
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
6
6
7
7
7
7
```

But..

```
$final=array();
foreach($list as $keyl => $valuel){
   foreach($order1 as $keyo => $valueo){
      if($valuel==$keyo) {
        $final[].=$valueo;
      }
   }
}
print_r($final);
```

gets me just 7, last element..

Something wrong with recursion/life of var? But I can't seem to get it..

Comment: Try `$final []= $valueo;` (remove the period)

Comment: have tried.. getting same thing..

Comment: OK, my original arrays were made by explosions of some strings, in list array there were spaces on the end of each value :/ Trough print_r that wasn't visible. Only last member didn't have space. I have echoed arrays in <textarea> and that's how I found out.. I have trimmed order array since its explode is more complex but forgot to trim list.. omg... so much time wasted over a silly space :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the part you're interested in is the "value" of `$order1` which has indexes you'll know, you won't need the inner-loop and instead you can just use `isset()` to verify that the index exists and, if so, reference it directly.

For instance:

```
$final = array();
foreach ($list as $index => $key_name) {
    if (isset($order1[$key_name])) {
        $final[] = $order1[$key_name];
    }
}

print_r($final);
```

[**Codepad Example**](http://codepad.org/ATSjeIzr)

Comment: @Dario It works just fine, are you sure you have your arrays setup correctly (and did you copy+paste my answer, or attempt to re-type it)? I copy+pasted it and it's working fine - http://codepad.org/ATSjeIzr

Comment: Yeah, It seems that something is probbably wrong with my original arrays, as I said in comment below, they have some cirilic chars in them, I'll have to look into that..

Answer (score 2):

I think you messed up in your array initialization as the following code work as you expect (from what I understand)

```
$list = ["Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Bannana", "Mango", "Mango", "Mango", "Mango", "Mango", "Pear", "Pear", "Pear", "Pear", "Pineaple", "Strawberry", "Strawberry", "Watermelon", "Watermelon", "Watermelon", "Watermelon"];
$order1 = [
  "Apple" => 1,
  "Bannana" => 2,
  "Mango" => 3,
  "Pear" => 4,
  "Pineaple" => 5,
  "Strawberry" => 6,
  "Watermelon" => 7
];
$final=array();
foreach($list as $keyl => $valuel){
   foreach($order1 as $keyo => $valueo){
      if($valuel==$keyo) {
        $final[].=$valueo;
      }
   }
}    
print_r($final)
```

Comment: It realy is so.. I have simplifyed code for question purpose, in my real arrays there are some Cirilic characters, I'll have to look if that has some thing to do with the "problem"..